Next 14 Conditional Rendering Even When False
This component will always render true, even though the console logs false (which is correct).
Despite the component being on the client, I feel it has something to do with server rendering failing to hydrate correctly. Perhaps I'm missing something.
I'm using Next 14.2.15.
"use client";
import cookie from "js-cookie";

function getCookieValue(){
    const cookieVal = cookie.get("cookie");
    return cookieVal 
        ? JSON.parse(cookieVal) 
        : null;
}

function ProblematicComponent(){
    const [isVisible] = useState(() => {
        const cookieValue = getCookieValue();
        // Doing some synchronous calculations with the cookie here...
        const guardClause = true; 
        
        if(guardClause){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });

    // This ALWAYS results in false.
    console.log(isVisible);

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{
            // Context...
        }}> 
            <main>
                {/* Content */}
            </main> 

            {/* Despite the console.log being false, this ALWAYS renders and will display "true" */}
            { isVisible === true && (
                <span>{ String(isVisible) }</span>
            ) }
        </Context.Provider>
    );  
}


isVisible seems to be a function (as you initialized it in the useState), but you are never calling it. How can it return false ? Are you sure your snippet is valid ?

@Max If you pass a function as the initial state, it will be treated as an initializer. There is no need to call it.
